# How do I open a pdf file in a virtual console?

Tags: 12.04, pdf, virtual-console

I want to open pdf files from within the virtual console and view them in the console itself. Are there any applications that allow that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following

```
less your_pdf_file.pdf
```

Comment: You might have to do `eval "$(lesspipe)"` first, though IIRC that's done by default in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [fbi](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/fbi.1.html) to view pdfs which contain graphics. Here is a brief description of `fbi` taken from it's man page:

> ```
>     fbi  displays  the  specified  file(s)  on  the linux console using the
>     framebuffer device.  PhotoCD, jpeg, ppm, gif, tiff, xwd,  bmp  and  png
>     are  supported  directly.  For other formats fbi tries to use ImageMag‐
>     ick’s convert.
> ```

To install, use `sudo apt-get install fbi`.
To open a pdf using fbi just type `fbi file.pdf` in your tty.